# Faulty front read from synchronized queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, boost, blockingqueue

I am using Boost libraries in C++ to achieve a multithreaded IO queue for video file frames in OpenCV
I got an issue because the Push thread works well, but when all the video frames are read, the consumer function which Pops the queue return always the same frame and I am not sure why.

Here the Queue Class:

```
#include "videoqueue.h"

VideoQueue::VideoQueue()
{
    std::cout << "Class initialized" << std::endl;
}

void VideoQueue::InitReader(std::string filename)
{
    VideoQueue::cap = cv::VideoCapture(filename);
    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening video file" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File opened: " << cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) << " frames" << std::endl;
        framesAcquired = 0;
        framesAvailable = 0;
    }
}

void VideoQueue::start()
{
    while(framesAcquired < cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    {
        //frame read from file
        cap.read(captureFrame);
        //safe push
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(queueMutex);
        bool const was_empty = queueFrame.empty();
        queueFrame.push(captureFrame);
        //frames amount updated
        framesAcquired++;
        std::cout << "Frames acquired " << framesAcquired << std::endl;
        framesAvailable = queueFrame.size();
        //mutex unlock
        lock.unlock();
        if(was_empty)
            queueCondition.notify_one();
    }
}

bool VideoQueue::queueEmpty() const
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(queueMutex);
    return queueFrame.empty();
}

int VideoQueue::framesQueued()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(queueMutex);
    return queueFrame.size();
}

void VideoQueue::readFrame(cv::Mat &output)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(queueMutex);
    std::cout << "mutex lettura bloccato" << std::endl;
    while(queueFrame.empty())
    {
                std::cout << "aspetto" << std::endl;
        queueCondition.wait(lock);
    }
    output = queueFrame.front();
    queueFrame.pop();
    std::cout << "front pop eseguito" << std::endl;
    //framesAvailable = queueFrame.size();
    framesConsumed++;
    //mutex unlock
    //lock.unlock();
    //queueCondition.notify_one();
    std::cout << "Frames consumed: " << framesConsumed << std::endl;
}
```

with its header

```
#ifndef VIDEOQUEUE_H
#define VIDEOQUEUE_H

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

class VideoQueue
{
    public:
        VideoQueue();
        void InitReader(std::string filename);
        void start();
        bool queueEmpty() const;
        int framesQueued();
        void readFrame(cv::Mat& output);
    private:
        //std::queue<Mat> frameQueue;
        cv::VideoCapture cap;
        int framesAcquired;
        int framesAvailable;
        int framesConsumed;
        cv::Mat captureFrame;
        cv::Mat outputFrame;
        //concurrent queue
        std::queue<cv::Mat> queueFrame;
        mutable boost::mutex queueMutex;
        boost::condition_variable queueCondition;
};

#endif // VIDEOQUEUE_H
```

and the test program with thread initialization

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include "videoqueue.h"

void wait(int milliseconds)
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds));
}

int main()
{
    VideoQueue prova;
    cv::Mat frame;
    prova.InitReader("/home/exeless/DEV/C++/1_10_rest.avi");
    boost::thread t(&VideoQueue::start, &prova);

    wait(500);
    while(prova.framesQueued()>0)
    {
        wait(100);
        prova.readFrame(frame);
        std::cout << "frames " << prova.framesQueued() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "value " << cv::mean(frame) << std::endl;
        imshow("output",frame);
        cv::waitKey(10);
    }
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I think the issue is somewhere in the scheduling of threads, but I am not sure where. Any help would be great.

Comment: You notify your condition variable only when a queue was previously empty. It is possible that you miss the other events. It is completely ok to notify it after pushing each frame.

Comment: I have also tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried to separate the loop in `VideoQueue::start()` from an actual `VideoQueue::push()` but it doesn't seem to be caused by that.

I guess that the end of `VideoQueue::start()` is messing with the structure of the queue, but I don't know how and also gdb doesn't see any issue in the execution.

Comment: The other problem with this code is `while(prova.framesQueued()>0)` - this loop breaks as soon as the queue is emptied, not necessarily at the end of the movie. You should compare number of frames read with `cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)` like in a pusher method.

Comment: The problem is probably due to how `cv::Mat` is implemented -- it's really a kind of smart pointer (or handle) to the underlying data. Just assigning one `Mat` to another simply creates a reference to the original. Reading a frame from `VideoCapture` does not reallocate the `Mat` if it already exist. So you're basically populating your queue with references to a single buffer. Also, while your queue is synchronized, this buffer is not, and you can easily end up reading and writing at the same time. You need to do a deep copy when pushing into the queue.